# Dropbox Sync API - How to Sync Manually ?

Tags: android, dropbox

I am trying to implement `Dropbox Sync API` in my Android Application. I want to do the Syncing manually on `Click Events`. I have written this code:,br/>

```
private class BackgroundSyncManager extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    private boolean isSynced = false;

    private ProgressDialog pd;

    public BackgroundSyncManager(Context ctx)
    {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        pd.setTitle("Downlaoding in Progress...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        sync_Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        pd.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {
            pd.show();
            mDbFileSystem.syncNowAndWait();
                            isSynced = true;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            isSynced = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Error Occured While Syncing !, Error = "+e.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

But, it is throwing me an `Error`, Here is what my `Logcat` Says:

```
12-10 11:34:23.311: E/Main Activity(15464): Error Occured While Syncing !, Error = java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Am i doing the Manual Syncing Wrong, or is there some problem in this implementation ?
Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does mDbFileSystem.syncNowAndWait() do? From the exception, it says `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` which means inside syncNowAndWait() it invokes some APIs that should be called in UI thread instead of your own thread.

Comment: Yes i agree with you. But It is returning the same exception when i run it on UI thread.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The Sync API syncs continually, all the time, via long-polling. So "sync right now" doesn't mean anything... what would it do differently from what it's already doing?

Comment: Okay, actually i want to show the progress while the Sync is in process for the first time. because i am fetching some Meta Data of my Android App via DropBox and i need to create my Views according to that Meta Data, so technically i need to know when it has been synced and show a progress dialog with appropriate progress while the files are being synced for the first time.